# Charge payment "to", "on", or "against" a credit card/an account; charge a credit card/account/a person "with"an amount

Tags: word-usage

Are all of these options acceptable and in current use to denote payment with a credit card?

E.g.

Please *charge this amount **on*** me/my credit card/my (credit card) account.

Please *charge this amount **to*** me/my credit card/my (credit card) account.

Please *charge this amount **against*** my credit card/my credit card details (or information).

Please *charge me/my credit card/my (credit card) account **with*** this amount.

And also:

"Thank you for providing us (with) your credit card and for authorizing us...

to *charge it **with*** a deposit;

*Or*

to *charge a deposit (**to*** it);

*Or*

to *charge a deposit (**on*** it);

*Or*

to charge *a deposit (**against*** it)."

Thank you.

Comment: To charge a deposit means to demand a fee, for example, it is *de rigueur* in renting anything. It is called a security deposit. If one has pets, an additional fee, sometimes called a pet deposit, is required/demanded/charged. That is not used with credit cards. Deposits *are* however required with *debit cards*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please charge this amount <s>on me</s>/ *(to/on)* my credit card/my (credit card) account.

Please charge this amount <s>to me</s>/*(to/on)* my credit card/my (credit card) account.

Please charge this amount against my credit card/my credit card <s>details</s> (or information).

Please charge <s>me</s>/my credit card/my (credit card) account <s>with this amount</s>.

We usually just say "Can I charge it?" while presenting the card. However, all the above (save the ones I struck) are used. We also say "to my card".

When we want only a certain amount charged on the card (say you know you're near your limit and fear going over, or you're splitting the tab unevenly) you say, Please charge this amount *(to/on)* my credit card.

In long ago days, "charge me" was heard, but no longer routinely. If we did say that, it would seem like an taunt to press criminal charges.

Edited to add: <s>to charge it with a deposit; To charge a deposit (to/on it); to charge a deposit (against it).</s>

Comment: The correct preposition with "charge", with regards to booking an entry in an account, and thus in relation to credit cards, is "to". A charge on something is also used but in this case charge acts as a noun: "they took a charge on assets"