# charge $10 from/to me?

Tags: prepositions

Double-object verbs can be used in two structures,
e.g. He gave me this book. = He gave this book to me.

What about 'charge' (in the sense of asking for payment)?
For 'They charged me $10.', what should be the preposition in 'They charged $10 to/from me.'?

I know 'They charged me $10.' is the usual way to say it, but sometimes the description of the person charged can be very long (e.g. They charged Mr. Smith of the operations department of ABC Company $10.).

'to' is suggested ('Please charge this amount to my credit card/my account.') here: [Charge payment "to", "on", or "against" a credit card/an account; charge a credit card/account/a person "with"an amount](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155115/charge-payment-to-on-or-against-a-credit-card-an-account-charge-a-credi)

But this sounds like an accounting context. Is it the same for the case above?

Comment: _Charge_ doesn't work as nicely as some of the other verbs in the [Commercial Transaction Frame](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf). And you can't depend on _from_ or _to_ to have their usual meanings; more than money is being exchanged.

Comment: The direct object of _charge_ is normally the person being asked to pay. If you must use the sum as object, I think it has to be _to me_.

Comment: The charge is made _to_ the person but the money is demanded _from_ them. The charge is the means by which the demand is made. Thus "The cafe made a charge of $10 _to_ Mr Smith for the broken crockery" or "The cafe asked for $10 _from_ Mr Smith for the broken crockery". The demand passes to Mr Smith but the money comes from him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1a) The verb **charge** can take a direct object whose referent is the person charged (the DO often followed by a money phrase in relevant examples):

> - They charge you $20 just to get in the nightclub. [[Cambridge Dictionary; they wrongly classify this as a double object
>   construction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/charge)]:

(1b) Measure phrases are best considered not as an object but as a separate category.

- I walked 10 miles.
- It took her 3 hours.
- It cost me £12.

Note that these resist or disallow passivisation, unlike 'Tom bought 10 books' or 'Tom gave Jill a book.'

And prepositional alternatives are not readily available here:

- *It cost £12 off/to/for me.
- *It took 3 hours of/off/to/... her.

(But note

- It cost £12 for me just to get onto the platform.)

...................................

(2) The verb **charge** can alternatively take a direct object whose referent is the commodity being charged for:

- Charge the meal to me.
- Shall we charge the flowers to your account? [CD]

These are inflexible, with the DO followed by a to-phrase indicating the person, account etc to be debited. They don't allow dative transformation (*Charge me the meal.)

...................................

In your case, using a rewrite makes most sense:

- Mr. Smith, of the operations department of ABC Company, was charged $10 [by ...].

Comment: In constructions like "The airport charged him an additional fee for his three hockey sticks" and "I always charge him a commission" do "an additional fee" and "a commission" still qualify as  measure phrases? // [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge) has the example "charges $50 for an office visit" under a transitive sense for *charge*: "to fix or ask as fee or payment."

Comment: Yes, there are different analyses supported by different grammarians. 'Ann led him a merry dance' is or was claimed to be ditransitive by one (Oxford, I think) dictionary. I'm always very wary about constituency tests, but the passivised *'A merry dance was led him by Ann' shows that the latter example must at least be considered a dubious candidate for a ditransitive structure.  'The airport charged him an additional $20' has to use a measure phrase, so perhaps we just need a better hypernym for these strings. *'An additional fee/$20 was charged him.' // But the whole issue of DOs needs ...

Comment: sorting out, unless I've missed some definitive analysis. ... 'The piano had a stool' is non-passivisable. Allerton, in The Handbook of English Linguistics_eds Aarts and McMahon claims that post-verb non-passivisable noun groups such as appear in

'The piano resembled _a pianola_.' /

'The piano weighed _a ton_.' /

'The piano had _a stool_.' /
'The piano seemed _an antique_.'

should not be considered objects but 'are best regarded as belonging to a slightly different category'. 'The Passive and the Notion of Transitivity' by Monique De Mattia-Viviès is also well worth reading.