# Meaning of "against" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "against" in this sentence:-

> The facility of cheques 'against' demand deposits makes it possible to directly settle payments without the use of cash.

Comment: The first question is what a demand deposit is: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/demanddeposit.asp

Comment: It just seems to mean you can use a cheque to pay from money from your account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Charge payment "to", "on", or "against" a credit card/an account; charge a credit card/account/a person "with"an amount](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155115/charge-payment-to-on-or-against-a-credit-card-an-account-charge-a-credi)

Comment: does the "against" here means "in exchange for" or "supported by". As after searching I got to know that "against" could also mean those two. So which one suits it best or is it something else?